# How can the owner of an ubuntu-core be informed in advance about updates?

Tags: ubuntu-core

How can the owner of an ubuntu-core system be informed that an update will start soon?

I would like to connect an app to such a service in order to send a notification to a mobile phone, for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider posting this question in https://forum.snapcraft.io/

The closest thing I can find is being able to schedule an update window. I'm not sure this is natively supported.
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/system-options/87